# VSTS Build failing - Maven

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I am setting up build for my project in vsts. It is getting failed at Maven pom.xml step with below error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test-store-models-common: Failed to retrieve remote metadata test-store:test-store-models-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata test-store:test-store-models-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to mseng-visualstudio.com-zcalvinmaven (https://mseng.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/zCalvinMaven2/maven/v1): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. ->

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you’ve already added the correct build service identity to you feed (contribute), then you need to settings.xml with authorization token to the root of repository.

Refer to this article to check your steps: [Set up Team Build and Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/maven/maven-team-build)